# How can I add a title to multiclass.roc plots in pROC?

Tags: r, roc, multinomial, nnet, proc-r-package

I have a multinomial model constructed with `nnet:multinom` of 5 classes for 26 variables:

```
mirna_multinom_0 = multinom(formula_0, data= clase_training, maxit=10000 )
```

And then I create my ROCS with:

```
multiclass.roc(clase_training$clase, mirna_multinom_0$fitted.values,plot=TRUE)
```

Which I plot.

```
pred_test_inter_multinom_5 = predict(interaction_multinom_model_5, newdata = clase_test, "probs")
multiclass.roc(clase_test$clase, pred_test_inter_multinom_5,plot=TRUE)
```

[image: Plot of first contrast Ctrl vs Group1]

To understand them I store it as an object `e` and call the contrast as `names(e$roc)` to see my contrasts.

```
e = multiclass.roc(clase_training$clase, mirna_multinom_0$fitted.values)
names(e$rocs)

 [1] "Control/Idiop_grave"      "Control/Idiop_leve"       "Control/Isquem_grave"    
 [4] "Control/Isquem_leve"      "Idiop_grave/Idiop_leve"   "Idiop_grave/Isquem_grave"
 [7] "Idiop_grave/Isquem_leve"  "Idiop_leve/Isquem_grave"  "Idiop_leve/Isquem_leve"  
[10] "Isquem_grave/Isquem_leve"
```

Which gives me 2 plots for each of them, 1 in > direction and the other in < direction.

Now. **Can I plot the titles of each contrast in the plots in someway?**

And also, **is there a way I can obtain the areas under the curve AUC for each one of the ROC contrast?** I only obtain it in a message for the multinomial. Which don't have a PROC plot. **Can I obtain a multinomial ROC, or its just a construct with no graphical representation?**

Comment: Re "Can i plot the titles of each contrast in the plots in someway?": can you show what you've done so far (ie you say "Which i plot" but don't show us)?

Comment: Of course, sorry @Calimo. Going to edit it. Aaaand done.

Comment: I meant, can you show us the **code** that you use to make the plots?

Comment: My bad, i i thought i did. Edited. Its a multinomial model from nnet:multinom, thats why i obtain 20 of them, 5 levels, 2 contrast for each one of them. @Calimo

Comment: I didn't know that multiclass.roc accepted plot = TRUE. Clearly not very useful. See https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/issues/56 for future improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I plot the titles of each contrast in the plots in someway?

You will need to loop over the curves yourself, but it can be done easily like:

```
for (contrast in names(e$rocs)) {
    plot(e$rocs[[contrast]][[1]], col = "green", main = contrast)
    plot(e$rocs[[contrast]][[2]], col = "blue", add = TRUE)
}
```

> is there a way I can obtain the areas under the curve AUC for each one of the ROC contrast?

You can do something similar with the `auc` function:

```
for (contrast in names(e$rocs)) {
    print(contrast)
    print(auc(e$rocs[[contrast]][[1]]))
    print(auc(e$rocs[[contrast]][[2]]))
}
```

> Can I obtain a multinomial ROC, or its just a construct with no graphical representation?

It is a sort of average of AUC described by Hand & Till in [doi:10.1023/A:1010920819831](https://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1010920819831). There is no corresponding curve to be represented.